# Using 瑞士的瑞 to address the character 瑞

Tags: spelling

Since I'm not a native chinese, I need to confirm this with one.

For the character 瑞 would it be awkward if I refer to / address it when spelling a word to another person using 瑞士的瑞 ---> "Switzerland's Ruì" ?

瑞士 has the highest rank of frequent word that has the character 瑞 in it..

Please CMIIW

Comment: maybe take a look at this: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/30823/official-naming-of-the-characters-hanzi-in-mandarin-chinese/30826#30826

Comment: woopsy doopsy, I didn't see that..

Answer (score 2):

Not awkward at all. It is in fact a common way to refer to 瑞. Another option is using 瑞雪兆丰年的瑞.

Comment: what is 瑞雪兆丰年 ? is it famous among chinese people?

Comment: @Tomsofty33 it’s famous among Chinese people, infact it’s used often to talk of the character 瑞, like I wrote in my answer. Oxford defines it as: *timely snow augurs a good harvest*.

Comment: is there a link to that definition of oxford?

Comment: @Tomsofty33 here’s a Chinese definition http://www.zdic.net/c/e/172/385082.htm | my oxford def was from a paid for dict in Pleco - no public links im afraid

Answer (score 1):

瑞 is a character mainly used in names.  And this is a common way to refer to 瑞 using names "瑞士"(Swiss), "瑞典"(Sweden).

(In some province of China, you might be able to use the names of some important towns in the province. For example, 瑞丽)

Comment: Not really. We use 瑞 in names because it has a good meaning. Check the meanings in 瑞雪，祥瑞.

Comment: Just forgot those word, :(